# How to open a modal on-click of a ui-grid row?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How can I open a modal (to edit data) on click of a row in [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/)?

Something like this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0lDoKOg4kXXa51NlSuMg?p=preview), except it's in `ng-grid` and I need it for `ui-grid`.

Answer (score 1):

This link can be useful , it covers a basic guide to migrate from ng-grid to ui-grid https://technpol.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/upgrading-to-ng-grid-3-0-ui-grid/